# Feed Multiple Images in a batch item to an Conv2d Layer, reshaping issue

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have an input of:

```py
[batch_size, number_of_images, img_size_x, img_size_y]
```

e.g. `[24, 51, 28,28]`

Now I want to process each image of an item of the batch through a Conv2d-Layer and collect the outputs.

I would like to reshape the input using a layer

`tf.keras.layer.Reshape(1,28,28)`

to get something like `[1224, 1, 28, 28]`

which I can process.

This is a minimal example to reproduce the error

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

input_data = np.ones((24, 51, 28, 28))
output_data = np.ones((24, 10))

inp_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(51, 28, 28))
res1 = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1, 28, 28))(inp_layer)
perm1 = tf.keras.layers.Permute((2, 3, 1))(res1)
cnn1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding="same", activation='relu')(perm1)
flat = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(cnn1)
fc1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)(flat)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp_layer, outputs=fc1)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(input_data, output_data, batch_size=24, verbose=1)
```

I assume from the following error that this reshape layer requests the input in the form of `[24, 1, 28, 28]` but I need to pass `[24, 51, 1, 28, 28]`

```py
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 
Input to reshape is a tensor with 959616 values, but the requested shape has 18816
[[{{node Reshape}}]] [Op:StatefulPartitionedCall]
```

Do you have any recommendations or see another possibility to structure my model?

If I use tf.reshape this works fine, but I get trouble using Keras functional API, as the output of tf.reshape is no output of a proper Layer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all Keras model will add additional first dimension for batch. You want to concatenate several images in a single batch?

Comment: Yes, I want to concatenate several image in a single batch. Therefore I would assume that reshape extends the batch dimension from 24 to 1224 (as I got 24*51 pictures in total)

Comment: Batch dimension is created by model, so if you want to concatenate several image in a single batch, you can just set needed batch size. The only way to concat images is to create tensor (28,28,num_concatenations). I don't know if this makes sense.

Comment: I don't know if I asked the question clearly enough:


* in one item of a batch I got 51 pictures


* each picture should be processed by a Conv2D-Layer


* the outputs of the layer should be concatenated

Comment: Then I guess you should just concatenate images by third dimension, e.g. create (28,28,51) tensor

Comment: and then the third dimension would be the channel of the conv2d?

Comment: Exactly. And it will be eventually substitutes for number of filters

Comment: I think this won't help me, as I do not get the label for each of the 51 images

Comment: you can concatenate labels in the same way

Comment: I need the output in the form [24,51,64] (kernel size 64) and I will concatenate the labels (10 classes) so I get a result [24,51,74]

Comment: no you'll just get 10*51 output nodes, because labels will need to be concatenated

Comment: I don't get it, could you please provide me with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more about working with dimensions. Suppose you have an input and labels arrays. First dimension is 10 time the batch size just for the sake of example.

```
input_data = np.ones((240, 51, 28, 28))
output_data = np.ones((240, 10))
```

First you need to change the order of dimensions. It's described by second argument.

```
reshaped_input = tf.transpose(input_data, [0, 2, 3, 1]) #This outputs (240, 28, 28, 51)
```

If you have 51 separate arrays of shape (28,28,1) you can concatenate them. Should you need concatenating labels, use the same operation.

```
tf.concat([input_data for i in range(51)], axis=-1)
```

```py
batch_size = 24
inp_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(28, 28, 51))
cnn1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding="same", activation='relu')(inp_layer)
flat = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(cnn1)
fc1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)(flat)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp_layer, outputs=fc1)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(0.0001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(reshaped_input, output_data, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)
```

Remember, that if you cancatenate labels, you need to adjust output layer's nodes.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I tried it out, but I don't understand the advantage of feeding it in this manner into the Conv2d, as the channel is the first input, also I don't get what I need to do with the concat function.

Comment: As I said in the answer, this was more about reshaping an concatenation. What exactly are you going to do with it depends on your objective. Conv2d can accept either channel first or channel last format, it matters only for internal computation. Concat is just an example. It can be used to get (28,28,51) array from 51 arrays of (28,28,1). In case you need it

Comment: Now I understand, thank you very much. I think I didn't ask the right question and need to alter my question above to clarify my objective precisely tomorrow

Comment: I think it would be better to ask new question. And if this answer was helpful in any way, please mark it as accepted